# Reloading sqlgrey whitelists?

Tags: postfix, email-server, greylisting

I inherited admin duties of a postfix server despite having no postfix experience. It's running a service called sqlgrey that is causing all emails from `google.com` to be greylisted for 30 minutes. I have added `*.google.com` to `/etc/sqlgrey/clients_fqdn_whitelist.local` but I am not sure how to force sqlgrey to reload its whitelist. The documentation shows how to kill sqlgrey and how to start it as a daemon, but I don't know if that is safe or whether sqlgrey needs to be started as a specific user, etc. Any ideas?